# Extlib Dialog via https not work in IE

Tags: xpages-extlib

we have a xpage, that includes a dialog. Our site is called via https. In firefox the dialog is displayed, in IE an empty page (https://[SERVER]/[DB]/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.6.1/dojo/resources/blank.html) is displayed....

The typeahead also only works in firefox. We watched the firebug console, all resources are loaded via https....

PLEASE HELP!!!

thanks mario

Answer (score 0):

workaround, that works:
http://www.openntf.org/projects/pmt.nsf/66d9103768cc2fed85256c59006b5433/4fccbe1e644908e786257872002cd7ca!OpenDocument